# NSURLConnection delegate is not call when call from NSThread's function

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurlconnection

I sent `NSURLConnection` request it is working fine. Now I want to refresh the information i.e. resend the `NSURLConnection.Refresh` is working when call from IBAction of button. But is not working from `NSThread` method. How to I solve this problem. Here `NSThread` function for running the system time. When the time is equal to 1:00 am I want to refresh the API. But it is not call the delegate of `NSURLConnection`.

This is NSURLConnection code:

```
-(void)displays:(model *)place
{
  NSString *strs=[@"http://www.earthtools.org/timezone-1.1/" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",place.latitude,place.longitude]];

  NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strs]];

  NSURLConnection *reqTimeZone=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
  [reqTimeZone start]; //here request not get start
}
```

Above code is with in function called "displays" argument is one instance of class it has all place details.

NSthread function code:

```
- (void) setTimer {    
   //assign current time
    [self countDown];
}

- (void) countDown {
   //count the current time 

   if(hrs==12&& meridian==@"pm")

    [self display:(placedetails)];//it calls the displays function but NSURLConnection is not get start.

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(setTimer) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

Above display function is called placedetails assigned but `NSURLConnection` delegate is not called.

Comment: please help to me ... i spent full day. from the button function API call works. but not work in NSThread called function

Comment: For the delegate methods to be called, you need to attach runloop to NSURLConnection. Since you are creating a thread and not attaching NSURLConnection to thread's RunLoop, connection delegate methods won't get fired.

Answer (score 4):

For the delegate methods to be called, you need to attach your thread's runloop to NSURLConnection. Since you are creating a thread and not attaching NSURLConnection to thread's RunLoop, connection delegate methods won't get fired.

Here is an example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    // I am creating a button and adding it to viewController's view
    UIButton *bttn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [bttn setFrame:CGRectMake(100.0f, 200.0f, 120.0f, 50.0f)];
    [bttn setTitle:@"Download" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [bttn addTarget:self action:@selector(spawnThreadForDownload) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [[self view] addSubview:bttn];
}

- (void)spawnThreadForDownload
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(downloadAndParse) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void)downloadAndParse
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"];
        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData 
                                         timeoutInterval:20.0f];
        NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];

        // Run the currentRunLoop of your thread (Every thread comes with its own RunLoop)
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

        // Schedule your connection to run on threads runLoop.
        [conn scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    }
}

// NSURLConnectionDelegate methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Connection failed with error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}

// NSURLConnectionDataDelegate methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Connection finished downloading");
}
```